# Xbian unable to mount external hard disk

Tags: xbian

I have a RPI running Xbian. My external hard disk is connected to the powered hub. Xbian used to mount the hard disk and was able to access the files earlier, but recently it stopped mounting the hard disk. It was unable to mount the hard disk but I can see the hard disk light  blinking indicating its being continuously read.

- Is there a way can we see why its unable to mount?
- If xbian was not able to mount is there a way to mount it manually?

Thanks.

Comment: What error indication do you get? Did you try to mount it from the command line? Research `df` and `mount`

Comment: Hi @Bex, there is no error. The hard disk light keeps on blinking continuously and its not mounting the hard disk. I've checked with the df command it doesn't show that hard disk. The hard disk used to mount properly in xbian earlier. When I connected this hard disk to a laptop its mounting properly, so don't know what to do? any suggestions?

Comment: Does the HD works when attached to a desktop PC?